# How to execute a PL file in Linux?

Tags: linux, fedora, perl

I have a vmware-install.pl file that I need to execute. I double click it but Linux will open it in a text editor for editing.
How to execute this file? Can it be done from GUI?
In file's properties says "allow executing file as program".

I have Fedora 18.

---

Update:
I managed to open the console and navigated to my folder.
I have poked:

```
chmod +x vmware-install.pl
vmware-install.pl
```

the last line says:

> vmware-install.pl command not found...

but 'ls' lists the file there....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Run this instead:

```
./vmware-install.pl
```

The `./` refers to the current directory.

If you run it without `./`, Linux will look for a program called `vmware-install.pl` in your executable path, but the current directory is never in the path by default (for security reasons).

Comment: It says: usr/bin/perl: bad interpreter: no such file or directory.

Comment: Make sure that the first line in the file is `#!/usr/bin/perl` and not `#!usr/bin/perl` -- in case you edited the file accidentally.

Comment: no. I didn't touch the file

Comment: I checked inside the file. the first line is: #!/usr/bin/perl -w

Comment: Accepted. Continued here: http://superuser.com/questions/807162/perl-not-found

Answer (score 2):

"How to execute a PL file in Linux?"

A PL file in Linux (filename ending with .pl) is very likely a Perl-program. So run it with perl like this:

```
perl vmware-install.pl
```

It's often also possible to just:

```
./vmware-install.pl        #or:
where/the/file/is/vmware-install.pl
```

But this requires the execution bit (a `chmod +x` attribute) to be set on vmware-install.pl and also Perl must be installed on your Linux where the first line says (`head -1 vmware-install.pl`). If `perl vmware-install.pl` doesn't work, there might be two explanations for that: 1) your system don't have perl installed (unlikely on linux) or 2) perl is not installed in any of the folders in the `$PATH` environment variable. Try:

```
echo $PATH
perl vmware-install.pl
/usr/bin/perl vmware-install.pl
/usr/local/bin/perl vmware-install.pl
/whereever/your/system/has/perl vmware-install.pl
sudo yum install perl        #to install perl on Redhat, RHEL, CentOS etc
sudo apt-get install perl    #to install perl on Ubuntu, etc
```

Answer (score 1):

From the GUI:

1. Right-click on the folder and click "Open in Terminal"
2. Type ./vmware-install.pl

Comment: I don't have this option in the pop-up menu.