# Perl not found?

Tags: linux, fedora

I try to run a pl script in the console. It shows me this error:

```
bash: ./vmware-install.pl /usr/bin/perl: bad interpreter: no such file or directory.
```

What does it mean?

> whereis perl

returns just

> perl:

### And which perl returs: no perl in .... (bunch of folders)

I have Fedora 18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suspect Perl is not where it should be.

The way to check is with which `perl`. If this dosen't give you a location, perl is not in your path (for extra credit, try `whereis perl` if which perl works).

If perl isn't in your path,  you'll get `perl:` not cool. Time to ransack the system.

We can use locate to find anything called, or containing perl. You're *probably* looking for a binary. So we can try `locate perl|grep bin` - this should find any file called curl, and return any path which contains bin in it. In theory, you can find the full path here, and run /path/to/perl vmware-install.pl and it *should* work. I'd also consider the fact you may end up needing to do this as root, if its the script I think it is.

If perl is *still* not there, I'd ponder the unspeakable horrors your OS must have faced, since perl is generally installed by default.

Answer (score 4):

```
yum install perl
```

Try this before running your command again. Seems like perl isn't installed on your system.

Comment: And... I miss the obvious. I thought perl and python2 were essentially installed by default on every common distro